# User-controls are evaluated first while loading content on scroll

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I am using code [HERE](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspxwn-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx) to load my user-control on page scroll. This user control takes EVAL data from repeater. But I am getting following output:

[image]

The user controls are being loaded on top and then the table rows are loaded. I want to load each user control before its table. They all are getting loaded at the top. Why this is happening? What is the solution?

Following is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <uc1:WebUserControl runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" city='<%# Eval("City") %>' />
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;
                border: dashed 2px #04AFEF; background-color: #B0E2F5">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><u><span class="name">
                            <%# Eval("ContactName") %></span></u></b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>City: </b><span class="city"><%# Eval("City") %></span><br />
                        <b>Postal Code: </b><span class="postal"><%# Eval("PostalCode") %></span><br />
                        <b>Country: </b><span class="country"><%# Eval("Country")%></span><br />
                        <b>Phone: </b><span class="phone"><%# Eval("Phone")%></span><br />
                        <b>Fax: </b><span class="fax"><%# Eval("Fax")%></span><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Rest of the code you can find in the link: http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because you're declaring the user control on top of the table and the parser always parses from top to bottom.First add runat="server" to table control and give it a id.Then you'll need to Dynamically create your user control using c# or vb and then in the table's Load event render the usercontrol using

```
idOfUserControl.RenderControl()
```

Comment: How can I do this with a table created on runtime in a repeater?